# How to make UI elements around an app keep track of their own states

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a network client iOS app.  There is a "controller" object that is responsible for receiving updates from the network.  It should store / forward them to the various visible pages in the app.  One page may need some of the data, one page may need some other part.  There is overlap.

For example, a button needs to be highlighted or not based on the status of a device on the network.  Buttons on different pages may need to reflect this status.

I need to determine if my various view controllers need to handle this or if the UI elements themselves can do it.  In my example, I will need the UI button to react to events, probably based on it's "tag" field.

I've thought about implementing a category to "wrap" the various UI elements, but I'd like to use storyboard layout.  This seems convoluted.  Or, I can set tags on the UI elements and have the enclosing view controller gather all these up into a dictionary of UI elements and do the watching/updating using tags as keys.  Or...?

I guess I'd like some pointers on what model may be best.  I need this to be flexible and adaptable moving forward, so I'd can't have a bunch of code and IBOutlets for each UI item.  I'm trying to keep everything as generic as possible so that when I need to make changes, I can add UI elements, set their tags, and let their enclosing view controllers take care of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about it this way:

- Your app needs a model that represents the external state of the
  world; in your case, devices on the network.
- Another part of your app (probably a singleton with some
  timers) is keeping track of the state of the world (probably doing
  GETSs using NSURLConnection) and then updating your model.
- Your ViewControllers present a view to the user, and *observe* the state
  of your model, telling the views to change when the model does.  (e.g. your viewcontroller would observe that a device in your model changed state to offline and then set a corresponding myButton.enabled=NO).

Take a look at [iOS key-value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSKeyValueObserving) docs to learn more about that.  If you think you'll have many views observing the same aspects of the model, consider using the [NSNotification center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for that.  (I didn't realize that you had responded.  Gotta check my settings.)  I've been doing the KVO thing, and have largely developed the model you describe.  You say "if you think you'll have many views...", which I may or may not.  How many is many?  What I have been doing is having a centralized NSDictionary store the basic states of things, and then each button watches that dictionary.  Each time a button or other object is instantiated, it sets observing on the dictionary, and stops upon dealloc.

Comment: I guess the better distinction for notification vs. KVO is that with notification, the state change on the model needn't be boiled down to just one key.  On the flip side, for an already KVO-compliant object (like your dictionary), there's no new work to do to announce the state change.  I am sure there are performance implications, too (KVO probably needs to walk a shorter list to find out who's interested in a change), but I don't think they differ in basic complexity.

Comment: As I look again at your post, I see that you're trying to avoid doing so much custom setup for each view controller, sort of wish you could drop in model-watching interface elements with IB.  I also don't like filling up my VCs with dozens of properties pointing to UI elements.  But two things: 1) adding category methods is good, and compatible with IB, and, 2) One hook you have is the UI element's tag.  You can not only use that to find the element as you suggested, but also to encode things about the element, as long as you can make it fit into an int.